# Extract text between two underscores

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to rename a large number of **PDF** files that are in the following format:

```
_TEXT[1...n]_NAME[1...n]_SUFFIX[1...n]
```

Is there a way to extract ***TEXT [1...n]*** (amount of characters is different for every file) between two underscores using ***Power-shell***?

Is there a way to extract ***SUFFIX [1,2...n]*** (amount of characters is different for every file)?

Comment: Both easily doable. Please show your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Providing some sample inputs and their desired outputs can greatly expedite answering your question. It's recommended to do so.

Comment: I've tried Dir | Rename-Item {$_.name -replace ...} for some of the files. However, I wasn't able to remove text b/w underscores because characters are different for every file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Get-ChildItem` to retrieve a list of the PDF files. Then use something like `Select-String` to extract the required data.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path SomeFilePath -Filter '*_*_*_*.pdf'
$Files.BaseName | Select-String -Pattern '_([^_]+)' -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {
    $_.Matches[-1].Groups[1].Value # SUFFIX
    $_.Matches[-3].Groups[1].Value # TEXT
}
```

Since you don't clarify what you want to do with the extracted data, a lot is left to be desired here.

---

If you just want to remove text between underscores with `NewValue`, you can do the following. `$Position` is which item you want to remove between two underscores starting with `1`.

```
$Position = 1
Get-ChildItem -filter *_*_*.pdf | Foreach-Object {
    $temp = [collections.generic.list[string]]@($_.Name -split '_')
    $temp.RemoveAt($Position)
    $temp -join '_'
}
```

---

If you want to replace text between two underscores, you can do the following and just change `$Position` to meet your needs.

```
$Position = 1
Get-ChildItem -filter *_*_*.pdf | Foreach-Object {
    $temp = [collections.generic.list[string]]@($_.Name -split '_')
    $temp[$Position] = 'NewValue'
    $temp -join '_'
}
```

Comment: I just need to delete it. And then replace underscore with a date using Dir | Rename-Item {$_.name -replace ...}

Comment: Removing TEXT and SUFFIX are two independent instances. Some files have the _TEXT_NAME naming convention. And others, _NAME_SUFFIX. In both instances, I have to delete a string of characters.

Comment: It sounds like the number of underscores is not predictable. The of the type of value you want to remove is not consistent. So unless there is something specific about what you want to remove that can easily be matched against, this won't be a simple feat and chances are there will be mistakes unless the criteria can be narrowed down further. The filter can be changed to `*_*_*.pdf` instead to capture two and three underscore files. However, how do you know when to match data after the first or second underscore? Something else is needed. Is there something identifying about TEXT and SUFFIX?

Comment: The only thing I was able to think of is TEXT is between two underscores. If there is a way to delete a string of characters between two underscores that would work.

Comment: @user12837217 I added more examples of how to handle the TEXT. Let me know if that is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't get it to work. Do I enter the entire code as a single line or do I have to break it up somehow? If I hit Enter it takes me to a new line. And another thing is there are no numbers in titles, I added [1...n] to show that every file has a different a name. I that what you are referring to in $Position = 1? If it helps below are examples that are closer to the actual  project: #1) _Mary Smith_December Activity Positive  #2) _Gary Hill_March Marathon Negative. And I have hundreds of files in that format, I need to delete Mary Smith and Gary Hill part from every file.

Answer (score 0):

You could split it on the underscore.  The first array element is empty string.

```
'_TEXT[1...n]_NAME[1...n]_SUFFIX[1...n]' -split '_'


TEXT[1...n]
NAME[1...n]
SUFFIX[1...n]
```

Comment: Text1, Text2,Text3,Text4 are different strings of characters used as an example.

Comment: That would work too.  All that matters are the underscores.

Comment: Eventually, I need to delete TEXT b/w 2 underscores. What is the full code I need to use in order to do that?